# history.js remove query parameters from url

Tags: url-rewriting, history.js, html5-history

I am using [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) for my ajax website. One thing I can not realise, is how to change url from `http://mysite/default.aspx?myparam=paramvalue` to `http://mysite/` using History.pushState?

How to get rid of default.aspx?myparam=paramvalue?

I tried `History.pushState('','','/'); It does not work

Thanks mates

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using History.pushState('','','/'); but with `http://mysite/` as your third function input (path parameter).

`History.pushState('ajax','title','http://mysite/');` for example.